# Create a distinct array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to distinct my array called "myCar" and list down the name of the car depend on their color.

I have this array..

```
let myCar = [
    {Name : 'Saab', Color : 'Red'},
    {Name : 'Volvo', Color : 'Green'},
    {Name : 'BMW', Color : 'Black'},
    {Name : 'Toyota', Color : 'Black'},
    {Name : 'Audi', Color : 'Red'},
];
```

I create a simple function called "distinctArray()" and it look like this..

```
function distinctArray(array) {
    let distinct = [];
    array.forEach((element) => {
        if (!distinct.includes(element.Color)) {
            distinct.push(element.Color);
        }
        let newElemVal = []
        newElemVal.push(element.Name)
        distinct.push(newElemVal)
        }
    );
    return distinct;
    }
let distinct = distinctArray(myCar);
console.log(distinct);
```

But the output is look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFq03.png)

I just want to get the color of each cars and list the car in an array. So, i want it like this way..

Expected Output:

```
[   
    "Red"
        [ "Saab", "Audi" ]

    "Green"
        [ "Volvo" ]
        
    "Black"
        [ "BMW", "Toyota" ]
]
```

I'm not sure what is lacking with my code but is there an easiest way to get the exact data?

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group all the values with the same color into an object, then map over each key-value pair to create the final array.

```js
let myCar = [
    {Name : 'Saab', Color : 'Red'},
    {Name : 'Volvo', Color : 'Green'},
    {Name : 'BMW', Color : 'Black'},
    {Name : 'Toyota', Color : 'Black'},
    {Name : 'Audi', Color : 'Red'},
];
let res = Object.entries(myCar.reduce((acc, {Name, Color}) => {
  (acc[Color] ??= []).push(Name);
  return acc;
}, {})).flatMap(([k, v]) => [k, v]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! @Unmitigated. It help's me a lot.